# 20 век или ХХ век?

Tags: орфография, числительные

Пишут и так, и так. А как все-таки будет правильнее: арабскими или римскими цифрами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Конечно же, **век**, **тысячелетие** обозначается римскими цифрами: ХХ век,  II тысячелетие до н. э. и т. д.

Comment: Это не может иметь обязательный характер, только рекомендательный. И скажите, пожалуйста, кто может это регламентировать?

Comment: Из справочника Розенталя: "...использование римских цифр для обозначения порядковых числительных ограничено: они применяются только при существительных век, столетие, ассамблея, конгресс, съезд, конференция и подобного типа, например: XX век, XX столетие, VII съезд народных депутатов".
См. Д. Розенталь "СПРАВОЧНИК ПО ПРАВОПИСАНИЮ, ПРОИЗНОШЕНИЮ, ЛИТЕРАТУРНОМУ РЕДАКТИРОВАНИЮ", §46. И ещё: правила не рекомендуют , а учат писать правильно.

Comment: Просто если проводить аналогию - на мой взгляд, в тексте романа, сказки или еще какого-то нибудь подобного текста - лучше числительные писать полностью. В технических и научных текстах - если напишут, не XX век, а 20-й век, то ничего страшного не случится. Это ж не переходить дорогу на запрещающий красный сигнал светофора. Честно говоря, использование римских чисел выглядит каким-то анахронизмом - просто укоренившейся привычкой носителей языка.

Comment: С Вами можно и поспорить, и кое в чем согласиться. Технари дотошны в цифрах, как по мне, им все равно, как ХХ век написан - римскими или арабскими. И, наверное, в технической л-ре не сильно придерживаются языковых норм, поэтому такое правописание и встречается.

Comment: Техническая литература должна соответствовать ГОСТам. Как мне кажется, они должны придерживаться правил русского языка.

Comment: Укажите ГОСТ, в котором говорится, что нужно писать "XX век", а не "20-й век"

Comment: Ничего, что я в ваш междусобойчик влезу?  
Я не вижу у Соана или Валентина (тем более - у Розенталя) утверждения, что использование арабских цифр запрещено или не рекомендуется. Если, тем не менее, кто-то стоит именно на этой позиции, то я присоединяюсь к просьбе обосновать её ссылками на авторитетный источник. Споры же о ГОСТах и юридических основания - это тупик.

Comment: В правилах нормативного русского языка никто не увидит слово "запрещено", а объясняется, в каких случаях следует писать-говорить так, а не иначе. Т. е. это языковая норма и ее нужно придерживаться. Языковой ГОСТ - это справочники под редакцией 1. Лопатина; 2. Розенталя. Может, в дальнейшем и будет правильным написание арабскими 20-й век, как в других странах, но сейчас норма  - ХХ в. И всё. Действительно, спорить об этом можно бесконечно.На ресурсе "Грамота.ру" нашла интересное интервью. Посмотрите. Оно не  по нашей теме, а о языковых новшествах. http://www.vesti.ru/only_video.html?vid=464950

Comment: Согласна с @tmp. Там же ясно сказано: где _можно_ использовать римские цифры. Но совсем не сказано, что _нужно_.

Comment: >> в каких случаях следует писать-говорить так, а не иначе.   

Да Вот именно этого "не иначе" нету в том что вы цитируете.
А от Ваших трактовок герой Михаил Евграфовича вспоминается. "Нет такого закона, чтобы песни петь!"

Answer (score 3):

Оба варианта безусловно правильны.
Никаких ограничений на использование арабских цифр в подобных целях нет. Есть "разрешение" использовать римские цифры. 
Только имейте в виду, что при использовании римских цифр наращения не нужно, а для арабских оно обязательно: 20-й век, в 3-м тысячелетии и т.д. Если у вас есть трудности с выбором правильного варианта наращения (вот они-то строго регламентированы, об этом [здесь](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/?rub=rubric_99)), то пользуйтесь римскими.